# Unable to see the design view in VS2012 website forms

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

When I click on design view, the form basically gets unresponsive and then I am unable to click on the source. Then I have to close the form and reopen it to see the source view. Please help me.

[image: Clicking design view causes unresponsive VS]

Answer (score 2):

Try to re install Visual Studio 2012 It might solve your problem.